# PDF export in Mac OSX Mojave

Tags: export, pdf-format, mac-os-x

Exporting a simple graph as PDF in Mac OSX Mojave changes the text to a different, bold font:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Sin(x)",
FrameLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(3\)]\)"}]

Export["~/Desktop/test.pdf", g]
```

The exported graphic looks different than the one shown in the notebook. Under Mac OSX High Sierra the graph in the PDF file was identical to the one in the notebook. Is there anything simple that can be done restore the correct behaviour? I don't want to explicitly embed fonts etc. I am using Mathematica 11.3 and Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.

Comment: I also find this, happens for various different fonts I have tested. Font that gets embedded into pdf is same family but bold.

Comment: I have the same problem :(